# Eclipse running GUI client multiple times

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface

I am programming client/server game. I am using Eclipse. Client is with GUI by Swing. Until now, I ran server once and then I ran client, right click on class --> run as . Everything was ok. Now i need to run client class twice. I tried when server and client were running, just again rightclick on client -> run as. There was two client processes but only one GUI JFrame.

I want to test it this way, run server, run client, run client so two clients are running and then on first client I want to click on first button ( It's new game ) and on second client I want to click second button ( it's existing game connection ) but for me it's unable to run two GUI for two client processes. I have only first GUI for first client and then only running process of second client ( NO GUI )

Thank you very much,

Marek

EDIT :

SERVER - main

```
public static void main(String [] argv) throws IOException,ClassNotFoundException {
    ServerListen server = new ServerListen(PORT);
    server.acceptConnection();
}
```

SERVER - acceptConnection();

```
    Socket dataSocket = null;
    ObjectInputStream readBuffer = null;
    ObjectOutputStream writeBuffer = null;
    while( true ) {
        try{
            dataSocket = socket.accept();
            System.err.println("!!! Connection !!!");
            writeBuffer = new ObjectOutputStream(dataSocket.getOutputStream());
            writeBuffer.flush();
            readBuffer = new ObjectInputStream((dataSocket.getInputStream()));

            writeBuffer.writeObject("OKlisten");
            writeBuffer.flush();
            System.err.println("Client connected");
            new Handler(dataSocket,readBuffer,writeBuffer).runGame(list_of_games);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

This is running only once.

CLIENT - main

```
public static void main(String [] argv) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    Client client = new Client(PORT);
    final Basic frame = new Basic(client);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

P.S - you see the println of !!! Connection !!! and when I do right-click --> run as on client second time there is no second !!! Connection !!! message

THANK YOU VERY MUCH

EDIT 2.

```
public Client(int PORT)
{
    try{
        this.clientSocket = new Socket(serverName, PORT);
        sendMessage = new ObjectOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
        sendMessage.flush();
        getMessage = new ObjectInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
    }
```

This is part of code, in second client, it froze on getMessage line.

Comment: Eclipse does not prevent multiple GUI processes running simultaneously. The problem is more likely located in your code when you run the client and another client is already connected. Does your server correctly handle multiple incoming connections?

Comment: @schmop  . I will edit the post, you will see the code that there is nothing why it shouldnt work, it worked as console programme, now i am adding only GUI and want to test it

Comment: Yes, it is exactly what I am saying: the problem isn't multiple GUIs, it's multiple server connections. Put a trace before `Client client = new Client(PORT);` if you need to convince yourself that the process is being launched more than once.

Comment: `"you will see the code that there is nothing why it shouldnt work..."` -- Seriously. Until you figure out why you have a bug, the first thing you have to do is to get rid of all assumptions, such as this doozy.

Comment: @schmop , you are right, thank you. This is my client constructor, where I dont know where is mistake, I used debugger but he shown me only the line where it froze. It is getMessage line. Can you help me please ?

Comment: User: use background threading, either via a SwingWorker or a basic Thread by having your Client implement Runnable and running it in a Thread.

Comment: Does `new Handler(dataSocket,readBuffer,writeBuffer).runGame(list_of_games);` create a new thread? Are you sure `dataSocket = socket.accept();` is being called a second time? Put a trace BEFORE `dataSocket = socket.accept();` to make sure the server code properly resets after a first connection.

Comment: @schmop , In previous version, it was working with multiple clients. Now the server is stuck at "new Handler" and dataSocket = socket.accept() is not called second time and I have no idea why, I am looking for old version where it worked.I used code tutorial from Java cookbook ( o'reilly ). I thought that new Handler would make a new thread and that it should work for another client.

Class Handler extends Thread

Comment: SOLVED : I misunderstood threads. I need to use .start and run method not runGame method :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run any long-running bits of code, such as your `while (true)` loop in a background thread, else you risk tying up the Swing event thread, freezing your application.

For example, your code could look something like:

```
// implement Runnable so it can be run in a background thread
public class MultiServer2 implements Runnable {
   public static final int PORT_NUMBER = 2222;
   private static final int THREAD_POOL_COUNT = 20;
   private List<MultiClientHandler> clientList = new ArrayList<>();
   private ServerSocket serverSocket;
   private ExecutorService clientExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREAD_POOL_COUNT);

   public MultiServer2() throws IOException {
      serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT_NUMBER);
   }

   @Override
   public void run() {
      // do this in the run method so that it runs in a background thread
      while (true) {
         try {
            Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();

            // MultiClient2 also implements Runnable
            MultiClientHandler client = new MultiClientHandler(clientSocket);
            clientList.add(client);

            // and each socket's code needs to be run in its own thread
            clientExecutor.execute(client);
         } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO notify someone of problem!
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
      }
   }
```

with a main method that looks something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  try {
     MultiServer2 multiServer = new MultiServer2();
     new Thread(multiServer).start();  // this runs the runnable
  } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```